# Numix circle theme - change one Icon

Tags: 15.04, icons, icon-themes

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on a Thinkpad T450. I installed numix-circle-theme like that:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme-circle
```

and used the unity tweak tool to set the icons to numix circle.

Everything looks real nice except my KiCAD icon. It seems as is should be here (https://github.com/numixproject/numix-icon-theme-circle/issues/179) so I investigated and under /usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/48x48/apps there is a kicad.svg.

So why is is not showing the new circle icon of KiCAD?

Comment: $ `cat /usr/share/applications/kicad.desktop`

Comment: @reversiblean
[Desktop Entry]
MimeType=text/pro
Name=KiCad
Exec=kicad
Icon=icon_kicad.png
Categories=Development;Engineering;Electronics
Type=Application

Should I change it to kicad? or the other one to icon_kicad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/kicad.desktop`

Try changing the icon field to just **kicad**.

You don't need to have their full path specified, but their filename without the extension.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Just had to log out and in again.

If I wanted to change the icon with one I designed my own, where would I put it? /usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/48x48/apps will probably get overwritten when there is an update?